# How can I unit test a TPL Dataflow pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, .net-6.0, tpl-dataflow

Given the following pipeline class I want to test the actual LinkTo(s) such that if I pass bad input into the DeserializeBlock I can check that DeserializeFailedBlock was called.  I'm looking for best practices on how to test that?

```
public class MyPipeline
{
    public readonly TransformBlock<byte[], PipelineMessage> DeserializeBlock = new TransformBlock<byte[], PipelineMessage>(input => Deserialize(input));
            
    public readonly ActionBlock<PipelineMessage> DeserializeBlockFailed = new ActionBlock<PipelineMessage>(input => DeserializeFailed(input));
            
    public readonly TransformBlock<PipelineMessage, PipelineMessage> ValidateBlock = new TransformBlock<PipelineMessage, PipelineMessage>(input => Validate(input));
            
    public readonly ActionBlock<PipelineMessage> ValidateBlockFailed = new ActionBlock<PipelineMessage>(input => ValidateFailed(input));
            
    public readonly ActionBlock<PipelineMessage> PublishBlock = new ActionBlock<PipelineMessage>(input => Validate(input));
    
    public MyPipeline()
    {
           DeserializeBlock.LinkTo(ValidateBlock, message => message.IsValid)
           DeserializeBlock.LinkTo(DeserializeBlockFailed, message => !message.IsValid)
    
           ValidateBlock.LinkTo(PublishBlock, message => message.IsValid)
           ValidateBlock.LinkTo(ValidateBlockFailed, message => !message.IsValid)
    }
    
    public PipelineMessage Deserialize(byte[] message)
    {
    ...
    }
    
    public void DeserializeFailed(PipelineMessage message)
    {
    ...
    }
    
    public PipelineMessage Validate(PipelineMessage message)
    {
    ...
    }
    
    public void ValidateFailed(PipelineMessage message)
    {
    ...
    }
    
    public PipelineMessage Publish(PipelineMessage message)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Begin writing your code to interface.

Comment: can you clarify your response?  do you mean interface out the individual methods such as deserialize, validate, publish?

Comment: You would need to input bad data and then check if whatever side-effect `ValidateFailed` has happened.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  How can I capture that a particular block has received a message?

Comment: How would any of us know? You omitted its implemenation. What you could do is increment some counter and make it publicly available or trigger an event ... many things are possible. If you add those failed items into a deadletter queue, you could use that ...

Comment: You don't need more interfaces to begin with. Dataflow methods already work through extension methods on interfaces anyway. Each block can be tested independently, simply by passing messages and retrieving outputs from their output buffers. If you extract the delegates into separate methods you'll be able to test them separately too

Comment: `capture that a particular block has received a message?` that's not unit testing any more, that's integration testing of the entire pipeline. It's what you do once you have unit tests for the blocks themselves.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am guessing OP is interested in testing the setup of the blocks: mind the filters set in the `LinkTo` calls. - I'd agree it is more of an integration test, than unit. But regardless of name - that's what OP wants to be tested.

Comment: That's testing of the pipeline, not the blocks. It's easy to do by replacing those ActionBlocks with BufferBlocks and inspecting their contents at the end of the method. Or replacing the implementation of `ValidateXYZ` with something that generates a testable output.

Comment: Another possibility is to record the path of each message on its envelope (PipelineMessage ?).

Comment: Yes integration test would have been a better term to use.  I already have unit tests for each of the methods that the datablocks call, I am looking to test the actual pipeline.  What I left out is that sometimes I route to a null target block if the input to a transform block is null.